# Nodejs triggers function before previous function finish

Tags: node.js, file, asynchronous, download

What I need to do is,

1. to check if `fileFullPath` exist
2. if not, in the end of successfull file download, to call `saveInfo`.

When I execute the application, what I observe is, it calls `saveInfo` before finishing file write operation. And I get error message:

```
(node:20224) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: BatchCluster has ended, cannot enqueue -charset
```

What am I doing wrong?

```
async function dl(url, path, data = null) {

    await request.get({
        url: url,
    })
        .on("error", async function (error) {
            console.log(error);
            return false;
        })
        .on('response', async function (res) {
            var fileExt = res.headers['content-type'].split('/')[1];
            var fileFullPath = `${path}.${fileExt}`;
            await res.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(fileFullPath));
            console.log("file downloaded");
            if (data) {
                await saveInfo(fileFullPath, data);
            }
        });
    return true;

}

async function saveInfo(filePath, data) {
    await exiftool.write(filePath, {
        Keywords: data.keywords,
        Copyright: data.copyright,
    });
    console.log("Tags are saved");
    exiftool.end();
}
```

Comment: What is `request.get()`?  Is that [this library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request).  If so, it does not return a promise so using `await` on it does nothing useful.  Also, `await res.pipe()` is similarly wrong.  `await` only does something useful if you `await` a promise.

Comment: @jfriend00 const request = require("request");

Comment: @jfriend00 can you help me to modify this function to got, please?

Comment: Please show code for `saveInfo()` also.  What is the function suppose to return?

Comment: @jfriend00 updated

Comment: Does `exiftool.write()` return a promise?  Please provide a link to that library.

Comment: @jfriend00 https://www.npmjs.com/package/exiftool-vendored

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208529/discussion-between-demonoid-and-jfriend00).

Answer (score 0):

OK, I found a way to do this.  piping to streams is not very friendly to promises so I ended up doing some manual promise manipulations.  I think better promise support for streams is coming to node.js as we already have some async iterators.  Anyway, here's a way to make things work by watching for the right events on your streams:

```
function dl(url, path, data = null) {

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        request.get({
            url: url,
        }).on("error", function (error) {
                console.log(error);
                reject(error);
        }).on('response', function (res) {
            let fileExt = res.headers['content-type'].split('/')[1];
            let fileFullPath = `${path}.${fileExt}`;
            let writeStream = fs.createWriteStream(fileFullPath);

            // set up event handlers to monitor the writeStream for error or completion
            writeStream.on('error', reject).on('close', async () => {
                if (data) {
                    try {
                        await saveInfo(fileFullPath, data);
                    } catch(e) {
                        reject(e);
                        return;
                    }
                }
                console.log("file downloaded");
                resolve(true);
            });

            // send the response stream to our file
            res.pipe(writeStream).on('error', reject);
        });
    });
}

async function saveInfo(filePath, data) {
    await exiftool.write(filePath, {
        Keywords: data.keywords,
        Copyright: data.copyright,
    });
    console.log("Tags are saved");
    exiftool.end();
}
```

Comment: @demonoid - If you're running the code in my answer, that error is not because the file is still open.  This code does not call `saveInfo()` until the writeStream is closed.  This code fixes that part of the issue.  Also, please put a `.catch()` handler on `dl()` when you call it.  The unhandled rejection is likely because you aren't catching errors when they happen.  The error appears to be happening inside of the exiftool module.  You will need to do some further debugging to figure out why it's getting an error.

Comment: I places try and catch

Comment: filepath must be relative, right? like 'folder/child_folder/file.ext'

Comment: @demonoid - You probably need to pass a fully qualified (not relative) pathname to `exiftool.write()`.  It's going to fire up another process to do its work that won't necessarily have the same current working directory.